# UIMA Ruta: set feature with MARKONCE action

Tags: java, uima, ruta

`MARKONCE`: I have a sequence of sentences ending with question sign, and I want to annotate the entire span at once. So, I use `MARKONCE` to accomplish this task.

Now, I also need to set the feature for this newly created annotation. How to set the feature through `MARKONCE` ? (in the same manner like `CREATE` action allows).

In other words, I would like to have:

```
String testRule = (Sentence{ENDSWITH(QUESTION)})[2,10]{->MARKONCE(QuestionSeq, "deviceType"="parallelism")};
```

Why is it not possible and what would the solution(if any) be?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with MARKONCE because MARKONCE is a really simple action.

However, there are several ways to do this in Ruta. Here are two examples:

You could avoid additional matches, e.g., with -PARTOF():

```
(Sentence{-PARTOF(QuestionSeq), ENDSWITH(QUESTION)})[2,10]
       {->CREATE(QuestionSeq, "deviceType"="parallelism")};
```

or you could simply set the feature value with a separate action:

```
(Sentence{ENDSWITH(QUESTION)})[2,10]
       {->MARKONCE(QuestionSeq), QuestionSeq.deviceType="parallelism")};
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*